# JSON Response Model design issue

Tags: json, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I need help with designing the JSON response models of our API.

Let's say a `getUsers` call returns the following response model:

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Bob Jones",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "3",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "companyId": "4"
        },
    ]
}
```

Now we have another call, let's say `getUsersWithCompany`.  This includes company information.  The question I have is:

**Should I include this additional `company` data into each `user` or should it be a whole new `companies` list in the response model?**

### Solution 1: Combining user and company

```
{
    "usersWithCompany":
    [
         {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "company":
            {
                "companyId": "3",
                "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "123123123"
            },
        },
         {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "company":
            {
                "companyId": "4",
                "companyName": "Another Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "463463383"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

**Advantage:** This might be easier when the model is consumed as the company data is available as the user list is being traversed.

### Solution 2: Separate lists for user and company

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Bob Jones",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "3",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "companyId": "4"
        },
    ],
    "companies":
    [
        {
            "companyId": "3",
            "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
            "contactNumber": "123123123"
        },
        {
            "companyId": "4",
            "companyName": "Another Company Ltd",
            "contactNumber": "463463383"
        },
    ],
}
```

**Advantage:** This ensures that the user and company items are always consistent across calls.  Less variety for the consumer.

We are using .NET Web Api 2.

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP and .NET?

Comment: If you are referring to the `asp.net-web-api` tag then it's because we are using that technology.

Comment: But you don't use these technologies anywhere in your question. In fact, your question is relevant for *every* RESTful system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design should take into account if the entities are weak or strong. (where weak means they don't live if the main entity is deleted). So for users and companies, I'd have a separate RESTFULL service like

```
/users
[
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Bob Jones",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "3",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "companyId": "4"
        },
]

/companies
[
        {
            "companyId": "3",
            "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
            "contactNumber": "123123123"
        },
        {
            "companyId": "4",
            "companyName": "Another Company Ltd",
            "contactNumber": "463463383"
        },
]
```

You also need to consider if you have some other reference to the companies catalog besides the users. If that is the case, I'll be even convinced about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would start out with the single list of combined company and user objects (pledging YAGNI "You ain't gonna needed it" wrt. to the double list). This is the most widely used solution I have seen - and it allows you to easily add more user-related information later on.

Later on, if it turns out that payload size becomes an issue (maybe because you simply have too many users in one response), you can add a new method/service that returns an optimized version of the result. But remember that zipping the output can get you a *long* way wrt. payload size - for free!

But "optimized version" can be different things: you suggested one solution (two lists), but maybe you later on discover that a better optimization would be to only return some kind of "incremental" or "delta" result wrt. a previous response.

It all depends on your use cases - and premature optimization makes you spent efforts were it may never be needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest treating user and company as different resources. You can use a query parameter to specify whether or not to include the company information in the user payload.

```
GET /users

{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "company":
            {
                "self": "http:/my.server/companies/3"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}

GET /users?expand=company

{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "company":
            {
                "self": "http:/my.server/companies/3",
                "companyId": "3",
                "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "123123123"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

This allows you to only get user information when you need it, to bundle company information when you need it, and to follow the URI from a specific user to their company without having to build the URI on the client. By keeping company as a separate resource, you also give yourself room to work with companies without needing a user as a reference point.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the second solution because

1. This ensures that the user and company items are always consistent
   across calls (as you mentioned).
2. No need to maintain separate models for different APIs (like getUsers, getUsersWithCompany)
3. There will be no redundancy of information. (which will save network bandwidth)
4. If you bind the companies and users to UI models, it is easy to get the details from companies model based on Id.
5. If there is any change in company details, no need to refresh/update users model.

Answer (score 1):

I see company how connection of user, i had written an and i had chosen this method for resolve this problem

/user return list of users
/user?connections=OUT return all connections is output of user model.

I thinks that you can send this information in only one route, for example

/user return list of users

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Bob Jones",
            "companyId": "3"
        },
        {
            "userId": "3",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "companyId": "4"
        },
    ]
}
```

/user?company=true return

```
{
    "users":
    [
        {
            "userId": "1",
            "name": "Joe Soap",
            "company": {
                "companyId": "3",
                "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "123123123"
            },
        },
        {
            "userId": "2",
            "name": "Bob Jones",
            "company": {
                "companyId": "3",
                "companyName": "Some Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "123123123"
            },
        },
        {
            "userId": "3",
            "name": "Mary Jane",
            "company" : {
                "companyId": "4",
                "companyName": "Another Company Ltd",
                "contactNumber": "463463383"
            },
        },
    ]
}
```

But if I can choose between your solutions I prefer the first

Answer (score 1):

I do think you need to include what company those users belong. But here a few key points:

- If you return the complete company object, people who are using your service would need to check
  if the company information has changed on every call, that would add more complexity to your users. I would return just the company id and use an adjacent service to fetch those companies.
- I highly recommend another field to track when this user information was changed, like a time stamp or hash. That would make your service easier to use, since people wouldn't need to iterate over the array to check if each user information has changed on every call. That works for every service you provides.

Keep in mind that with a huge amount of data, returning a small set of data would get a performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 is being congruent: is telling you the user and its company.

Solution 2 is not. Is giving you users and, by the way, companies. Two things at once.

You need Users and their company information? Then giving them the users and, per each, the company is what the requester wants.

If you give them users and companies separated, the requester will have to link them.
Which is unnecessary, as if the requester wanted companies would request them. Requester wants Users and their companies!

Answer (score 0):

If you're designing an interface for the web, you should always keep the responsetime in mind.
Beside academic architecural matters, this will be one of the major challenges you will face.

Ask yourself: How many tuples of User and Company entities may be returned by this call. Keep in mind, that the result will get pretty large over time.

You will try to keep the information density (=Entropy) of these interfaces very high.
This means, you try to eliminate redundant pieces of information.

Your solution two achieves these goals. And it has another benefit:
It's easier for your interface consumer to unmarshal the response on his side.
All Company entities are (hopefully) unique and there will be no necessity for validating the integrity and similarity of the returned company entities compared to the checking needed in solution one.
Marshaling and unmarshalling JSON is, like every linear String operation, quite time consuming compared to other types of operations. The shorter your String is, the quicker the result will be returned to the consumer.

**Sidenote**:
If you go with solution one and send this response over a gzipped http connection, 
the loadtime won't be much slower on the http channel compared to solution two. The GZIP protocol does a pretty good job to erase these string redundancies you create with the company entities.